# Portable XAML Styles in a Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, portability

So I have an application with a style put directly into the App.xaml file as such:

```xaml
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SpecialButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Block.Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness}">
                                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                        <ContentControl Foreground="White">
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I want to include this as a style in my class Library, so that any xaml projects that reference that library can see "SpecialButtonStyle" as a selectable "Style" in the designer.
I've read several articles about ResourceDictionaries and creating portable XAML controls, but I'm still confused. I basically want a collection of styles included as part of a class library.

(I can only post 2 links until I get a higher StackOverflow reputation)
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/03/01/everyone-gets-xaml-with-xamarinforms.aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you read is correct.

What you need is to create a plain `ResourceDictionary` inside your shared assembly with a given name.

In your `App.xaml` you then can include this `ResourceDictionary` as a `MergedDictionary` and therefore your whole app will have access to all of the shared dictionaries resources.

Steps:

1. Create another project WPF Control Library Project (doesn't matter about User or Custom)
2. In the new project right click -> Add -> ResourceDictionary
3. Paste your style in so it looks like the following:

**Dictionary1.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="SpecialButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Block.Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <ContentControl Foreground="White">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

4. In your main project reference this new Control Library
5. In `App.xaml` reference `Dictionary1.xaml`

`App.xaml`

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                 StartupUri="NestedXamlObjects.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will comment back as soon as I have the opportunity to implemented this.
PS. I can't upVote until I have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this post. If you are using Xamarin.Forms or .NET MAUI, you also can do it this way.

I manage all my styles in a shared class library project (same as step 1-4 from the accepted answer) and
add the `ResourceDictionary` as shown below.

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KlipperRemoteControl"
             xmlns:shared="clr-namespace:AndreasReitberger.Shared;assembly=SharedMauiXamlStylesLibrary"
             x:Class="KlipperRemoteControl.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <shared:DefaultTheme />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

DefaultTheme.xaml form the library.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="AndreasReitberger.Shared.DefaultTheme"
    
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Controls/BoxView.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Controls/Editor.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Controls/Entry.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Controls/Label.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Controls/Grid.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Controls/Frame.xaml" />
       
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Color x:Key="Transparent">Transparent</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TappedBackgroundColor">#eaeaea</Color>

    <Color x:Key="Green">#33AD79</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LightGreen">#38ef7d</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkGreen">#11998e</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Red">#ff4a4a</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkRed">#93291e</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Orange">#F78836</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkOrange">#F83017</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Blue">#3C8CF1</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LightBlue">#6dd5ed</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkBlue">#2193b0</Color>
    <Color x:Key="HyperLink">#567cd7</Color>
    <Color x:Key="White">#ffffff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Black">#000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="primary-lighter">#edcacd</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Liliac">#d483fc</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Purpleish-Blue">#5d4cf7</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Link">#567cd7</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Bright-Cyan">#3cdeff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Lemon-Lime">#bdff27</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Yellow">#E9B31A</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Pink">#C6275C</Color>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas for this answer! I couldn't find a proper example anywhere else!

Comment: Using this approach, I was able to get my code to compile (no other approach worked). However, my MergedDictionary does not contain any keys. I can see my referenced Dictionary in `App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries`, but the Dictionary does not contain any items.

Comment: Is it possible to globally reference resources in the class library itself? So a XAML in class library can use those resources?