# Maui using style.xaml from a class libary

Tags: xaml, maui

I've created 2 projects in Maui. The first is a class library with a resource dictionary in it. The second is the actual app I want to use the resource dictionary so I tried referencing it in the `App.xaml`.
I have setup the GuiLibrary as a dependency of the app that needs to use it
All attempts have this at the top in the application section of the `App.xaml`

```
 xmlns:gui="clr-namespace:AppGuiLibrary;assembly=AppGuiLibrary"
```

I've tried the following different combinations to no success.

1. `<ResourceDictionary Source="AppGuiLibrary/Styles.xaml"/>`
2. `<ResourceDictionary Source="/AppGuiLibrary;component/Styles.xaml"/>`
3. `<ResourceDictionary Source="/gui;component/Styles.xaml"/>`

The `Styles.xaml` is a Maui.Xaml content type.

The error I got for all of them is

> Resource X not found

Does anyone know what I'm missing to get this to work?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/29858235/199364.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your question?