# Using shared xaml style resources in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-8.0

Not much of a code problem here, but some structural and understanding issues. What I'm trying to achieve is to have Style resources shared between different projects.

I have two .Net MAUI projects with the same structure in the same Visual Studio solutionI also have a third project in the same solution, MyResources, which includes shared resources between the two projects.

At the moment, the two Style and Color pages of my two projects are identical, and what I'd like to do is to move them to the MyResources project so I can have a single Style page tp edit. Is it possible, and if so how can I achieve this ?

```
| Project[1/2]
|   | ...
|   | Resources
|   |   | Styles
|   |   |   | Colors.xaml
|   |   |   | Styles.xaml
|   | ...
| ...
| MyResources
|   | Resources
|   |   | AppIcon
|   |   | Fonts
|   |   | Images
|   |   | ...
```

I am able to access theses resources by using the following code in my `Project[1/2].csproj` file :

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="..\MyResources\Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#121725" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="..\MyResources\Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#121725" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="..\MyResources\Resources\Images\*" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="..\MyResources\Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="..\MyResources\Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What I've tried : after several unsuccessful ideas, in the App.xaml file of my projects, I tried changing :

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Into :

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../MyResources/Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../MyResources/Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Edit : I've added a [minimal reproductible example](https://github.com/gchapeaux/MauiMRDTest) of the situation, based on the basic Maui project, I'm trying to use the styles for the buttons from the MyResource project instead of the app projects themselves.

Comment: You want to remove the Style resources in other projects and want to share it between different projects, it's pretty similar to [Portable XAML Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858235/portable-xaml-styles-in-a-class-library), you can refer to it.

Comment: So basically, I should just use instead :
`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyResources;component/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyResources;component/Styles/Styles.xaml"/>` ?
I'm a bit confused with URIs, never had to work with them until now, will have a look on it.

Comment: I tried it this way, and I end up with an error : "Invalid URI : Invalid port specified". It seems to come from the "pack"mention, am I missing something ?

Comment: It could be related with the semicolon in the source url.

Comment: The semicolon before "component" ? I copied it straight from the documentation

Comment: May I know which doc?

Comment: Sorry, I meant from the answer in your first comment

Comment: I didn't saw any error message in that documentation, have you missed or forgot to add something?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit confused here. The message error I get is the one I quoted in my previous comment, "Invalid URI : Invalid port specified", and my project doesn't compile. I'll be adding a minimal reproductible example in my question, maybe it'll help making my question clearer. Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Thanks for your update, I'll look into your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay turns out I found out the solution !

I needed to make a few changes, I went on the right path by looking at [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-8.0#merge-resource-dictionaries-from-other-assemblies) of the documentation.

The first problem was the shared ResourceDictionary needed to have some **background code**, for the main project to be able to find it in the external assembly (*Right click on MyResources project > Add > New element > .NET MAUI ResourceDictionary (XAML)*, this way it comes with a background .cs file, and we can just copy the content from the previous default dictionaries). The Dictionary then comes with a defined `x:Class` that can be referenced in other projects.

Then we needed to be sure MyResource was **referenced in my Projects** (*Right click on Project1/2 > Add > Project reference*) and to **reference the assembly in the App.cs file of my projects**, by adding `xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyResources.Resources.Styles;assembly=MyResources"` to the App.xaml root.

Finally, instead of trying to get the Source right and work with these shady `pack` URIs, we just had to **import it using the namespace** in the MergedDictionary : `<res:MyDictionnary/>`.

My final App.xaml code :

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<!-- I renamed my namespace in my shared dictionary code from MyResources.Resources.Styles to MyResources.Shared, but it works as well. -->
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project2"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyResources.Shared;assembly=MyResources"
             x:Class="Project1.App">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <res:SharedColors/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The Github repo in the question will be updated to reflect the fix.