# Merge dependent ResourceDictionaries from external assemblies in .Net Maui

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

For anyone who wants more context, this question is the continuation of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77496192/using-shared-xaml-style-resources-in-net-maui).

I want to use for a Maui App styling two ResourceDictionaries from an external assembly, one for Colors and one for Styles. The very first goal was to have two apps in their own project, and common styling resource in an idnependent common project. I managed to import my dictionaries by setting my App.xaml file like this :

```xml
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project2"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyResources.Shared;assembly=MyResources"
             x:Class="Project1.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <res:SharedColors/>
                <res:SharedStyles/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My problem is my `SharedStyles` dictionary uses colors defined in `SharedColors`, and when I compile and run my app it seems SharedStyles can't find resources in SharedColors (error message : `StaticResource not found for key Primary` with `Primary` being a color defined in `SharedColors` and used in `SharedStyles`).

The workaround I found was pretty easy, I just had to move my color definitions in `SharedStyles`, however I would like to be able to use two different dictionaries, and maybe in the future to define some app-only styles that can use these colors.

Is there a way to have these two dictionaries merged this way not in the assembly they're from, but in the app using them ?

In case it could be relevant, this is how I define my styles in `SharedStyles`, I just reproduced what was in the default project, and it works well when I define my colors in the same dictionary :

```xml
<Style TargetType="ActivityIndicator">
    <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: For now, I think you need to move the color definitions in `SharedStyles` and use two different dictionaries merged may not be approachable.